# Correct Mathjax source in RStudio and RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, mathjax, r-markdown

I create a R Markdown file in RStudio , then I click on the `Knit HTML` button on the top of the screen to create and save an HTML page which I want to use elsewhere, say store it on my server.

The problem with the HTML file, is that it contains

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

which is not valid anymore, and when I edit the HTML and change the source to the following it works.

```
https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

Any way I don't have to edit every time the HTML, but have the correct source from RStudio?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was changed in the `rmarkdown` package just about a month ago (see [this commit](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/099eb3f73498f30b509971ed7efeda9574bb86f0)). You just need to install the latest version of the rmarkdown package:

```
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

(of course, you'll also need to `install.packages("devtools")` if you don't have devtools.)

Incidentally, even without this step, you can tell rmarkdown where you want to get MathJax from. This is useful if you want to point to a different CDN.

```
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: https://d3eoax9i5htok0.cloudfront.net/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

Finally, you can eliminate your MathJax CDN dependency entirely by using `mathjax: local` to use a built-in copy of MathJax in rmarkdown (note that you'll also need to set `self_contained: no` to do this).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.